# Como utilizar ponto e virgula em javascript injetado?

Tags: javascript

Como psso escrever um alert cujo conteúdo possua um ponto e virgula `;` se o mesmo é considerado como elemento de sintaxe?

Exemplo:

```
<span onmouseover="alert("isso significa bla bla; voce acredita?";>Isso</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Só será parte da sintaxe do JavaScript se estiver fora da string, as strings começam e terminam com aspas:

```
"..."
```

Ou apóstrofos:

```
'...'
```

O problema do teu script é que você esta usando aspas `"` no HTML e no `alert` (que é Javascript injetado) ao mesmo tempo, fora que falta uma aspa de fechamento do HTML:

```
<span onmouseover="alert("isso significa bla bla; voce acredita?");>isso&lt/span>
```

Para evitar isto, dentro dos eventos nos atributos HTML use apenas apostrofos, faça o teste:

```html
<span onmouseover="alert('isso significa bla bla; voce acredita?');">isso</span>
```

Você também pode usar a entidade `&quot;` dentro do atributo de evento em HTML, que será equivalente as aspas:

```html
<span onmouseover="alert(&quot;isso significa bla bla; voce acredita?&quot;);">isso</span>
```